# CakePHP - Log in a user automatically

Tags: cakephp, authentication

How do you log in a user automatically without knowing their password?  I can get any information on the user from the database (username, ID, email, etc.) but the password will be the hashed version in the database so Auth::login() fails because the password is not the clear-text version.

Any ideas?  This must have been done before but I can't find anything.

As far as I can tell, Cake 1.3 used to allow you to provide just a user ID and it would log them in but Cake 2.x doesn't support that anymore so how is this done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All that Cake uses to tell if a user is "logged in" is by checking the session. So, just populate the session.

```
$user = $this->User->read(null, 1);
$this->Session->write('Auth', $user);
debug($this->Auth->loggedIn());
```

This skips past the authentication processes and skips even trying to identify them. But now they're in the session so as far as the app is concerned, they are logged in.

Comment: FYI, this is also how I "log" users in and out within test cases.

Comment: Thanks, that works.  Is this any less secure than trying to make a custom authentication handler, etc? Are there any other security issues with doing it this way?

Comment: Nope, shouldn't be, except if you expose the id as a parameter and make the action that logs a user in publicly accessible. That would be bad :)

Comment: Okay. Make sure your id hash is salted and it should be alright.

Comment: Using Security::hash() should mean my application salt is automatically used, right?

Comment: No. By default, it does not. `Security::hash($id, null, true);` will. The last parameter tells it to salt, the `null` parameter tells it to use the app salt method instead of a custom one.

Answer (score 2):

look at my Qlogins:
http://www.dereuromark.de/2012/02/08/qlogin-quicklogins-fur-cakephp/

especially
https://github.com/dereuromark/tools/blob/2.0/Controller/QloginController.php#L57

there I do it based on the key provided. but you can easily see how you can automatically log someone in by just knowing the user_id etc:

```
if ($this->Auth->login($user['User'])) {}
```

the trick is to pass the user data on to the method.

Answer (score 0):

See [Auth::identify()](http://api20.cakephp.org/class/auth-component#method-AuthComponentidentify): Use the configured authentication adapters, and attempt to identify the user by credentials contained in $request.

If it returns true redirect or do whatever you like.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how to do that?  I read the book already and it doesn't really make sense.  How do I make a custom authentication handler to just check a user ID, then login using that authentication handler?

Comment: Check the method, it takes CakeRequest and CakeResponse as params. Just make sure the CakeRequest has the user data in. If you just want to pass an id you'll have to write a custom handler, right. This is explained in detail here http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html#creating-custom-authentication-objects